# Obtener valor de comboBox Java

Tags: java, condiciones, combobox

Tengo un comboBox, el cual contiene diferentes opciones, analizadas cada una de estas mediante un if else if para cambiar el texto de una etiqueta, al momento de seleccionar cualquiera de las opciones del comboBox, se queda atorado en el primer if, omitiendo las demás opciones, de su ayuda amigos.

```
private void comboDivisasUnoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    //Asignamos la divisa a una variable para obtener el valor de esta misma, se regresa en forma de String
    divisaUno = (String) comboDivisasUno.getSelectedItem();

    //Comparamos el valor obtenido con cada uno de los campos del ComboBox
    if (divisaUno.equals("Estados Unidos - Dólar")) {
        etiquetaDivisaUno.setText("E");
    }else if(divisaUno.equals("México - Peso")){
        etiquetaDivisaUno.setText("M");
    }else if(divisaUno.equals("Europa - Euro")) {
        etiquetaDivisaUno.setText("EU");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jalim Vera! Bienvenido a SOes. Veo que eres recién llegado al sitio, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Dicho lo anterior, he probado el código que compartes y ha funcionado según lo esperado, sugiero que verifiques que el contenido del texto en el ComboBox coincida con el que pones en los equals, también hay que ver si pudiera ser un problema derivado del alcance de la variable "divisaUno", yo sugeriría trabajarla con un alcance restringido  al método en cuestión para descartar esta posibilidad.

Comment: Gracias, ya he realizado el recorrido, con respecto al comentario del programa, he verificado el texto del ComboBox con los equals y es exactamente el mismo, como meramente copiar y pegar, he cambiado la variable divisaUno de global a local y tampoco es el problema.